# Fetching all old emails when creating a new record in leads by incoming email in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8, odoo-9

Auto lead generation from email is generating the leads but it is fetching all my old emails.I required only the new mails which are coming present should redirect to leads.So,anybody can help how can i resolve this.

Comment: use the timestamp of mail.mail

Comment: Where can I configured the timestamp.I did not find any option timestamp in mail.mail